# Could not connect Apache Spark-2.1.0 with Hive-2.1.1 metastore

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

Both Spark and Hive are working fine individually but when I try to write the output of a Spark Dataframe to a Hive table, I am getting the below error :

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Hive
>   Schema version 1.2.0 does not match metastore's schema version 2.1.0
>   Metastore is not upgraded or corrupt

The details of "schematool -dbType postgres -info" are attached below :
[Schematool Results Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztbty.jpg)

**Additional Note : From this [Databricks Spark documentation page](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/30/integrating-central-hive-metastore-apache-spark-databricks.html), I found out that Apache Spark supports multiple versions of hive from 0.12 upto 1.2.1 only.**

So the only way for me to connect is to downgrade my Hive version ?
Or is there any other provision for us to add additional jars that enables to write Spark-2.1.0 DataFrames into Hive-2.1.1 tables ?

Appreciate your opinions on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I myself found the answer. Will be helpful to those who stuck with the same issue.

It is resolved by adding the following parameter in the hive-site.xml file

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This doesnt work, it just changes the schema version in metastore, which causes Hive to fail then. @JKC did you face this?